# Validating checkbox is causing troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm setting up a sign-up form, and user has to accept the conditions before he can submit the form. However, I haven't found a way to succesfully validate the checkbox. It has to be checked, or the user can't continue, and if it's checked --> continue with the script. However, my code isn't working as I want it to, and I'm asking for the correct way to do this.

```
var Ehdot = $('checkbox[name=ehdot]').is(':checked');
if((Nimi==="")||(ehdot === false)){
if(Ehdot == false){
            alert('Olethan lukenut ehdot ja hyväksyt ne?');
            $('checkbox[name=ehdot]').focus();
            return false;

            }
            return false;
}
```

A fiddle about this: http://jsfiddle.net/utWYs/1/

*If someone dares to say why I'm not using Validate plugin, I **kill** a kitten. [image: This one right here.]*

*I don't want to use a plugin for this, as it will make the site a bit heavier and  I won't learn anything.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small bug in your code .

```
var Ehdot = $('checkbox[name=ehdot]').is(':checked');
```

There is no element  named `checkbox` in your dom . This will returns always `false` .

you have to change this line to

```
var Ehdot = $('input[name=ehdot]').is(':checked');
```